# Is there a way to create parameterized type alias in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

So I have the following code:

```
@dataclass
class User:
    name: str
    age: int
```

The User class should correspond to some table in a DB where the name field is the primary key. I'd like to have the following type hints:

```
@dataclass
class User:
    name: Key[str]
    age: int
```

So I can further in my code check the type hints of the fields to find the name of the primary key. I'd like Key[T] to resolve to T so the normal type hints will work and check that the provided type is indeed str.
I searched a bit in the typing module's documentation and couldn't find any proper way of doing so.

Comment: If your goal is to represent database information using dataclasses, it might be a better idea to use a similar mechanism to [`dataclass.field`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field). Rather than declaring `name: Key[str]`, you could be doing something like `name: str = key()`. It's not quite as visually clean, but I think it is conceptually cleaner. If it's only for your own visual aid, `key = dataclasses.field` would probably work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `typing.NewType` if I understood your question correctly:

```
Key = NewType("Key", str)

@dataclass
class User:
    name: Key
    age: int
```

EDIT: You're looking for Generic NewType. It's an [open feature request](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3331) on mypy repo.

Comment: I need it generic

Comment: What's the gain from generic Key?

Comment: Different classes can have different db key type

Comment: To sum up, you want a meaningfully named type that can have the actual underlying type specified dynamically with `[]`?

Comment: Yes, I want to have both the underlying type and a meaningful named type

Answer (score 0):

If you need to validate, then you can:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

from validated_dc import ValidatedDC


@dataclass
class User(ValidatedDC):
    name: str
    age: int


input_data = {
    'name': 123,  # <-- not str!
    'age': 30
}

user = User(**input_data)

assert not user.is_valid()
assert user.get_errors().get('name')  # <-- There is an error in the name field
```

https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc